# Aptana ruby-debug-ide crash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, aptana, ruby-debug

i am using ruby-debug-ide with Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.4.1.201306062137.

Rails 3.2.13

ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]

ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11)

Sometimes (very often) when i refresh web browser (aptana server is runing in debug mode), server crashes with error:

```
[2013-07-22 13:04:05] An error occurred while processing the invoke block for the command ERb Content Assist in C:\Users\Rimantas\Aptana Rubles\rails.ruble\commands\content_assist.rb: (NoMethodError) undefined method `getInstance' for Java::ComAptanaIndexCore::IndexManager:Class
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NoMethodError) undefined method `getInstance' for Java::ComAptanaIndexCore::IndexManager:Class
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.index_manager(C:/Users/Rimantas/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:87)
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.gem_indices(C:/Users/Rimantas/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:79)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:274)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:229)
    at Java::JavaUtil::Collection.each(D:/IDE/plugins/org.jruby_1.6.4.1331328108/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/builtin/java/java.util.rb:7)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable.collect(org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:706)
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.gem_indices(C:/Users/Rimantas/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:79)
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.gem_and_project_indices(C:/Users/Rimantas/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:74)
    at Rails::ContentAssistant.assist(C:/Users/Rimantas/Aptana Rubles/rails.ruble/lib/content_assistant.rb:31)
    at #<Class:0x1013eaebb>.define_content_assist(C:\Users\Rimantas\Aptana Rubles\rails.ruble\commands\content_assist.rb:7)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:274)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(org/jruby/RubyProc.java:233)
```

How to fix debugger?

Answer (score 0):

Using another web server solves this problem. Add gem 'thin' to your gem file and run bundle install.